# How do I pull email address?

Tags: php, email, autofill, email-address

I'm putting together an eblast via sendblaster where I have a qualified list of email addresses; in the email copy is a link to a web page to look at a listing of products (on a web page) with a button to request bulk pricing. onclick I need the checked items and the email address of the person who filled in the form to be emailed back to a given email address including the user's email address (using php mail function for this). How do I pull the user's email address from sendblaster (or an IP address) and auto-fill it in the form?

Comment: you can use a dark-energy matter blaster..

Comment: @Raidenace: Are you sure? I tried that once... Didn't work! Ended up sucking all the mailing list addresses onto a micro black hole.

Comment: nothing as of yet; I have no real ideas on how to pull this data.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use #email# tag in your mail:
http://www.sendblaster.com/support/newsletter-creation/email-merge-software-tutorial-newsletter-personalization